# Update views in one Activity from another

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I am trying to emulate a software keyboard using an Activity with Theme.Dialog.  The keyboard activity covers only part of the screen.  The underlying activity is still active and can be controlled directly.  I would like the entered text to be displayed in the underlying Activity as it is typed.

Is there a way I can do this?  I was thinking of throwing a reference of my EditText into the Intent Bundle, but that does not seem correct.

**edit**: someone answered to make the EditText static, but then deleted the response.  Could they add it back in case this turns out to be the correct response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question because the person who supplied the original answer deleted it, and has not reposted it.

The best solution I've found so far it to create a static field in the software keyboard activity which refers to the EditText being manipulated.  The calling Activity then updates this static field before launching the intent.

This works seamlessly, and I've had no problems with the calling Activity getting blasted off the stack.

Answer (score 2):

It will not work.. your Activity will be in paused state.. you try to invoke something there it sure will throw an Exception.. don't try it.. try `onActivityResult()` instead...

**:Edited**

well then try this..

get the Activity instance (i mean the activity which has edit text) then

```
if(!yourActviity.isFinishing())
{

((EditText)yourActviity.findViewById(R.id.editText)).setText("text");
}
```

Comment: It is not in a paused state.  I can interact with the underlying activity directly.

Comment: @AndrewP. .. interactions involving UI..?

Comment: @sandy, yes.  I can click a button in the underlying activity which makes a native call and correctly updates the UI with the results.

Answer (score 1):

if u are using custom dialog u can acess the variables in main activity using its mainactivity context.for that u need to cast the context in mainactivity type

Comment: I'm not using a custom dialog, but a custom Activity with themed with Theme.Dialog.